# Kafka throwing timeout error on high load with error : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using Spring Kafka in my application, and when the load is too high, it throws the timeout exception:

```
Exception: Expiring XX record(s) for topic_name: 600904 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 54 record(s) for topic_name: 600904 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

I have tried with multiple producer configurations.

`Changed linger.ms to 0,10,100 and 1000. Changed batch.size to 131072 and 65000 Increased the request.timeout.ms to 100000 and 600000`
Rest, all the configs are mostly the default ones.

By changing these properties, we are reducing or delaying the errors a bit, but still not completely eliminating them.

I am using the Kafka send() method with a callback. I have tried calling this method async as well, but still no luck.

Each message would be around 4-6 KB. And 2-3 millions of messages are sent in a short span of time. We have a total of 10 partitions.

I have seen that calling flush() can help in this case, but that will reduce the performance and increase the sending time.

Is there anything else apart the configurations which can be done to fix this issue ?
Or if there is any other configuration which needs to be changed ?